# rjs type error in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs, modal-dialog

I add a `link_to_remote` to load a modal dialog box from a partial. But when I run the application I get the following error..

```
RJS error:

TypeError: $("create_event_dialog").dialog is not a function
```

When I click ok then again I got another dialog box.

```
Element.update("create_event", "<form action=\"/countries\" class=\"new_country\" id=\"new_country\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"new Ajax.Request('/countries', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"qWXCu2zMmlMhJG+GRf35kMbAIfzYAtFBee142ThmmMw=\" /></div>\n <p>\n    <label for=\"country_name\">Name</label><br />\n    <input id=\"country_name\" name=\"country[name]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n  </p>\n  <p>\n    <input id=\"country_submit\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create\" />\n  </p>\n</form>\n");   
$('create_event_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'New Event',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $('create_event_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

});
```

Why do I got this kind of error? I have a div with the id of `create_event_dialog`. I am using Prototype and I could not find the way to solve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like you want to actually use the **jQuery UI dialog** feature. As far as I know Prototype (or Scriptaculous) has no built-in dialog support.

If want to have a jQuery UI dialog you have two options:

1. Use jQuery and jQuery UI *alongside* Prototype.
2. Replace Prototype and *only* use jQuery

### Option 1:

To use jQuery alongside Prototype you have to include the jQuery Javascript libraries and enable the compatibility mode by calling `jQuery.noConflict()`. After that the `$` function belongs to Prototype and for all jQuery features you have to use `jQuery(...)` instead. For example `jQuery('create_event_dialog').dialog(...` in your case.

You can find details on **[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)**.

### Option 2:

You have to remove the Prototype libraries and instead include the jQuery libraries. You also need the [jRails compatibility library](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) to keep your prototype helpers. And you have to change your existing Prototype code to jQuery code.

For example your `Element.update` statement would look like this:

```
$("#create_event".html("<form action=...")
```

See **[Using jQuery with Ruby on Rails](http://jimneath.org/2008/06/18/using-jquery-with-ruby-on-rails.html)** for more details.

**Careful:** Depending on your existing code option 2 can be a lot of work, but will result in cleaner Javascript code. Also it might be worth considering switching to Rails 3.1 with UJS and jQuery as the official Javascript library.